# Sobre "estonce", "estonces", "entonce" y "entonces"

Tags: etimología, historia, adverbios

Hace poco descubrí que en el DLE hay hasta cuatro variantes de *entonces*:

- ***[Entonces](https://dle.rae.es/entonces)***, que viene de *entonce*.
- ***[Entonce](https://dle.rae.es/entonce)***, que viene probablemente del latín **intunce*.
- ***[Estonces](https://dle.rae.es/estonces)***, que viene de *estonce*.
- ***[Estonce](https://dle.rae.es/estonce)***, que viene de la preposición latina *ex* 'desde' y el adverbio *tuncce* 'entonces'.

Buscando en el CORDE veo que las dos últimas se usaron sobre todo entre los siglos XIII y XVI. De hecho en el Autoridades de la RAE (tomo D-F, 1732). Las variantes *entonce* y *entonces* también se prodigan por esos siglos pero parecen más usadas en desde el XV en adelante. De las cuatro, *estonces* parece haber sido la más usada inicialmente, en el siglo XIII, según el CORDE.

Hoy día, todas están en desuso menos *entonces*. ¿Cuál fue entonce la evolución de estas cuatro variantes del mismo adverbio? ¿Cómo es que llegó al español desde dos orígenes distintos? ¿Acaso cada variante pertenecía a una variedad dialectal diferente de por aquel estonce? ¿Cómo llegó estonces *entonces* a quedarse como la variante definitiva?

Answer (score 1):

*Estonces* aún se usa en judeo-español:

- [Studies in Etymology and Etiology: With Emphasis on Germanic, Jewish ...](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=l015C5vm1XkC&pg=PA449&lpg=PA449&dq=estonce+etymology) (p.449)

En cuanto a las dos formas, ambos vienen de la misma raíz:

- ex + tunc > estonce > [estonces](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/estonces)
- in + tunc > entonce > [entonces](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/entonces#Espa%C3%B1ol)

Hay multiples ejemplos de parejas así en castellano (dos palabras que antiguamente tenían connotaciones sutilmente distintas, pero se han convertido en sinónimos):

- eccum + hic > aquí
- eccum + hac > acá

Y de palabras que han adoptado otras morfemas por analogía de otras palabras comunes/para enfatizar su significado:

- quizá > quizás
- demás > además